# Post request is called twice in Express/Angular(not sure of express or angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

## Here is my Angular code

### Component

```
    onSubmit(formValue: any) {
        console.log("Form Value = " + JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 4));
        let newRegisterdUser = {
            firstName : formValue.firstName,
            lastName : formValue.lastName,
            email : formValue.email,
            password : formValue.password,
            phone : formValue.phone,
            location : formValue.location
        };
        console.log('Registered user in Angular : '+JSON.stringify(newRegisterdUser, null, 4));
        this._registrationService.saveRegisteredUser(newRegisterdUser).subscribe(
            (test : any)=> this.router.navigate(['registrationsuccess']),
            err => console.log(err)
          );
      }
```

### Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RegistrationService{

    constructor(private _http : HttpClient){}

    saveRegisteredUser(newRegisterdUser : any){
      console.log('test user : '+newRegisterdUser.firstName);
      return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/register/save',newRegisterdUser);
    }
}
```

### Express Code

```
var RegisteredUserApi = require('../data/FoodCourtApi');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.json({Hi : 'karthik'}); 
});

router.post('/save', function (req, res) {
    var registeredUser = {};
    registeredUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    registeredUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
    registeredUser.email = req.body.email;
    registeredUser.password = req.body.password;
    registeredUser.phone = req.body.phone;
    registeredUser.location = req.body.location;
   // console.log('Registered user in Node : '+JSON.stringify(registeredUser, null, 4));
    RegisteredUserApi.saveRegisteredUser(registeredUser, function (err, registeredUser) {
        // res.end();
        if(err){
            console.log('Hii');
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "save failed", err: err});    
        }else{
            res.json([{ statusSave: 'success' }]);
        }
    });
});
```

### MongoDB -- API Code

```
var RegisteredUserApi = {
    saveRegisteredUser: function(registeredUser, callback) {
        var newUser = new RegisteredUser(registeredUser);
        newUser.save({}, function (err, registeredUser) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
               return console.log('RegisteredUser inserted successfully.....!!!');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Two Network calls are triggered, one with OPTIONS and other with the POST. OPTIONS network call status code is 204 with no request payload and no response content. POST network call is taking the request payload and is getting failed after sometime(mostly after 3 minutes). But in the backend(Node & Mongo), i see 2 times the record is being inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
saveRegisteredUser: function(regis...
```

you need to call the `callback` function after saving the user.

Instead of console.log in `return console.log(err);` and `return console.log('RegisteredUser inserted successfully.....!!!');` use `callback(....)`

Your express app is simply not responding to any request to `/save` route. Neither this code `res.status(500).json({ error..` or this `res.json([{ statu....` was ever called.

```
var RegisteredUserApi = {
    saveRegisteredUser: function(registeredUser, callback) {
        var newUser = new RegisteredUser(registeredUser);
        newUser.save({}, function (err, registeredUser) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);  // <---
            } else {
               return callback('RegisteredUser inserted successfully.....!!!'); // <---
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @karthikvarmak cool, feel free to accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: In case of a delete operation, do we need to return any callback or just printing the console.log('deleting user') will be fine?

Comment: You should always responde to the request. If you don't then browser will make another request after first timeout.

Comment: Also you can still **accept my answer** as a correct answer :)